# Converting CSV file to UCS-2LE encoding with php

Tags: php, csv, mb-convert-encoding

I'm creating a csv file. I need it to be in UCS-2LE encoding. I tried the following, neither of which work:

- `$value = mb_convert_encoding($value,"UCS-2LE");`
- `$value= iconv( mb_detect_encoding( $value ), 'UCS-2LE', $value );`

Opening the file in Notepad++ shows the encoding to be ANSI.

Code:

```php
$file = fopen($filename,"w");
array_walk($csv_data, 'encodeCSV');

foreach ($csv_data as $line) {
    fputcsv($file, explode(',', $line));
}

fclose($file);

function encodeCSV(&$value, $key){
    $value = mb_convert_encoding($value,"UCS-2LE");
    //$value= iconv( mb_detect_encoding( $value ), 'UCS-2LE', $value );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the byte-order-mark ([BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)) at the beginning of the file. This should be '\xff\xfe' in your case:

```
$file = fopen($filename,"w");
fwrite($file, '\xff\xfe');
```